# Play a sound file slower or faster

Tags: command-line, audio, sox

How can you play a sound slower or faster? That would be useful for listening carefully one audio passage or to listen fast forward to find a concrete passage.

Is there something with the play sox command that would do this? Alternative simple solutions also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find almost half a dozen softwares recommended [here](http://ifdeflinux.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-slow-down-guitar-solo-with-free.html).

- Audacity
- MPlayer
- Rubberband
- Play It Slowly
- Ardour
- LMMS
- MuSE
- Rosegarden

Comment: I'll check these programs. Mplayer, which is command line and won't deform the pitch sounds promising. Audacity would be more for those people willing to convert a file (not my case).

Comment: mplayer -af scaletempo -speed 0.6 solo.ogg is what I needed.

Comment: @QuoraFeans, glad that the link resolved your problem :)

Comment: @QuoraFeans Audacity is **not** for people willing to convert a file - it's for people willing to modify or create music file. That is your case - and Audacity will do the great job. I've used it several times to change both pitch and speed of songs, as well as many different use cases.

Comment: @MatthewRock: you are right. Audacity allows all type of processing. Mplayer would be the tool of choice for some simple command line processing.

Answer (score 7):

I use the ffplay command (the sister of ffmpeg). There are two ways to change the speed of play: tempo and pitch. The former inserts or skips frames (it sounds like "glitches" in the music) but keeps the tone of the sound intact; the latter makes play smoother but affects the pitch.

The following is an example of adjusting the tempo:

```perl
# 20% increase, atrim — start to play from 120-th second of the file
$ ffplay -af "atempo=1.2,atrim=120" foo.mp3
```

The following is an example of adjusting the pitch (`foo.mp3` has the rate 44000):

```perl
# 54000/44000 ~+24% pitch up
$ ffplay -af "asetrate=54000" foo.mp3
```

ffplay is a very powerful tool; see more at the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/ffplay-all.1.html).

Answer (score 6):

Using sox / play

```
play file.wav   tempo 2    ##to play 2 times faster
play file.wav   tempo 0.5  ## ""             slower
```