# Programmatically change the playback speed (NOT pitch) in real-time

Tags: command-line, audio, sox

I'm looking for a software that reproduces audio files (wav and mp3 if possible) and provides a way to change the playback speed in real-time, flawlessy. I mean, without any gap, pop, or noise. Like the sampling clock is changed smoothly.

I'm NOT interested in maintaining the pitch constant (like this question: [Play a sound file slower or faster](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131143/play-a-sound-file-slower-or-faster)). Instead the pitch MUST follow the new speed.

I need to change the speed programmatically, say from 20% to 200% of the original one.

Is there something ready, without reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 4):

`mplayer` can playback `wav` and `mp3` files, and you can interactively change the speed with keys `[` and `]`, although wav files cannot be played slower than than their original speed. `vlc` can do the same and manages to slow down `wav` files too. Faster speeds move the frequencies up.

Comment: Same for `mpv`, a fork of mplayer. And both can play `wav` files at slower speeds on my machine.

Comment: @xhienne You are right. mplayer did slow down some wav files, but I had one sampled at 8000Hz which it failed to slow down, whereas mpv managed ok. Perhaps I just have an old version.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `mplayer -af scaletempo -speed 0.5 filename.mp3` to change the playspeed without changing the [audio pitch](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2009/05/29/mplayer-changing-speed-without-changing-pitch-avoiding-the-chipmunk-effect/).

If you would like to change the speed in real time (after calling mplayer from the command line), you will have to create run player in [slave mode](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/tech/slave.txt).

References:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36867732/slave-mode-mplayer-pipe
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856922/python-send-command-to-mplayer-under-slave-mode

https://github.com/ankitects/anki/blob/484377b8091179504b21b29be1de6925c70af4bd/qt/aqt/sound.py#L374-L404

```python
class SimpleMplayerPlayer(SimpleProcessPlayer, SoundOrVideoPlayer):
    args, env = _packagedCmd(["mplayer", "-really-quiet", "-noautosub"])
    if isWin:
        args += ["-ao", "win32"]

class SimpleMplayerSlaveModePlayer(SimpleMplayerPlayer):
    def __init__(self, taskman: TaskManager):
        super().__init__(taskman)
        self.args.append("-slave")

    def _play(self, tag: AVTag) -> None:
        assert isinstance(tag, SoundOrVideoTag)
        self._process = subprocess.Popen(
            self.args + [tag.filename],
            env=self.env,
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
            stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
            startupinfo=startup_info(),
        )
        self._wait_for_termination(tag)

    def command(self, *args: Any) -> None:
        """Send a command over the slave interface.
        The trailing newline is automatically added."""
        str_args = [str(x) for x in args]
        if self._process:
            self._process.stdin.write(" ".join(str_args).encode("utf8") + b"\n")
            self._process.stdin.flush()

    def seek_relative(self, secs: int) -> None:
        self.command("seek", secs, 0)

    def toggle_pause(self) -> None:
        self.command("pause")
```

Comment: The `scaletempo` allows change in speed but does not change the pitch. The OP specifically states, "_the pitch MUST follow the new speed_". Omit the `scaletempo` option entirely to allow pitch to follow speed.

Answer (score 1):

For those who need to set up speed from command line, use `-speed SPEED` option:

```
mplayer -speed 0.1 file
```

NOTE: you can change this speed in real time with `[` and `]` keys.

Of course, works for `mpv` as well.

Credits: https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux/tutorial-playing-around-with-mplayer/

Comment: As far as I understand, this doesn't address the question because you cannot change the speed parameter in real time as requested.

Comment: @Mark you're right. Should I delete the question?

Comment: Or just edit the answer adding that it doesn't work in real time. Perhaps others might find it useful anyway.

Comment: @Mark OK like this?

Answer (score 0):

For readers in 2022 with `mplayer` (in my case installed via `brew`), put this in your terminal config (in my case `.zshrc`):

```
alias mplayer="mplayer -af scaletempo=speed=tempo"
```

then during playing you can tune the playback speed via `]`(increase) and `[`(decrease). Don't forget that `/`(decrease volume), and `*`.

Answer (score -1):

As user said

```
mplayer -af scaletempo file.mp4
```

Is what you need. 
Scale tempo (speed) while maintaining pitch.
Basically the speed changes but you don't get the chipmunk/ghost effect when the speed is much higher/lower.

More info on scaletempo [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/audiofx/scaletempo.html?gi-language=c)

Now, using "[" or "]" you can increase/decrease the playback speed on the fly.

As that cannot be preset on settings (or I couldn't find how), I decided to create a **desktop entry** (kind of alias for an app in LXDE desktop) so I can open the relevant files from file explorer with that coded loaded in.

I leave it here in case someone wants it.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=mplayer scaletempo
GenericName=Media Player
X-GNOME-FullName=MPlayer Media Player
Comment=Play movies and songs
Keywords=Player;Capture;Audio;Music;Song;Video;Movie;Film;Clip;DVD;VCD;CD;Disc;DVB;TV;
Icon=mplayer
#TryExec=gmplayer
Exec=/usr/bin/mplayer -af scaletempo %F
Terminal=false
Categories=GTK;AudioVideo;Audio;Video;Player;TV;
MimeType=application/x-cd-image;application/x-cue;application/x-mpegurl;application/mxf;application/x-netshow-channel;application/ogg;application/ram;application/vnd.adobe.flash.movie;application/vnd.apple.mpegurl;application/vnd.rn-realmedia;application/x-shockwave-flash;application/smil;audio/aac;audio/ac3;audio/x-adpcm;audio/x-aiff;audio/AMR;audio/AMR-WB;audio/x-ape;audio/basic;audio/flac;audio/x-flac;audio/x-flac+ogg;audio/x-m4b;audio/x-matroska;audio/mp2;audio/mp4;audio/mpeg;audio/x-mpegurl;audio/x-ms-asx;audio/x-ms-wma;audio/x-musepack;audio/ogg;audio/vnd.rn-realaudio;audio/x-scpls;audio/x-voc;audio/x-vorbis+ogg;audio/x-wav;audio/x-wavpack;video/3gpp;video/3gpp2;video/dv;video/x-flic;video/x-flv;video/x-matroska;video/mp2t;video/mp4;video/mpeg;video/vnd.mpegurl;video/x-ms-asf;video/x-ms-wmv;video/x-msvideo;video/x-nsv;video/ogg;video/x-ogm+ogg;video/quicktime;video/vnd.rn-realvideo;video/x-theora+ogg;video/webm;x-content/audio-cdda;x-content/audio-dvd;x-content/video-dvd;x-content/video-svcd;x-content/video-vcd;
```

If you put that on a text file as blah.desktop you have your "new" application ready to be used from the window manager.

Comment: The `scaletempo` allows change in speed but does not change the pitch. The OP specifically states, "_the pitch MUST follow the new speed_". Omit the `scaletempo` option entirely to allow pitch to follow speed.