# Command line tool to playback audio at variable “turntable speed”

Tags: command-line, osx, audio

I’m looking for a command-line tool that can play audio from a file at a specified rate and pitch, preserving the rate-pitch ratio. That is, playback with a control analogous to the turntable speed on a record player.

(I *don’t* want to process audio with time-stretching algorithms that control tempo and pitch independently. The audio doesn’t need to be processed—just played back at a different rate. Time-stretching audio with equal rate- and pitch-ratios with tools such as [rubberband](https://github.com/breakfastquay/rubberband) is not real-time and still exhibits artifacting.)

Is there a tool that can do this in real time which works on OS X?

---

This is **not** a duplicate of questions like [Programmatically change the playback speed (NOT pitch) in real-time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/387803/programmatically-change-the-playback-speed-not-pitch-in-real-time).
I’m having trouble finding such a tool because most tools assume you want independent control of rate and pitch at the cost of sonic artifacts.

Comment: I think `sox` can do that, but I've never used it on osx. `sox InputFile test.wave tempo Factor`. Have you looked at that?

Comment: Yes; doing `sox InputFile -d tempo Factor` changes speed without affecting pitch. Doing `sox InputFile -d tempo TFactor pitch PFactor`, where `PFactor = 1200*log2(TFactor)` (converting a multiplicative factor to cents) is almost what I want, but sox still time-bends and pitch-bends in two steps, resulting in “choppy” distortions.